# Как авторизоваться в вк через консольное приложение на nodejs?

Tags: vkontakte-api, авторизация, oauth

Читал мануалы по авторизации в вк, все сводится к тому, что пользователю предлагается перейти на домен https://oauth.vk.com/authorize где он вводит логин и пароль и потом идет перенаправление на сервер, где уже сохраняется полученный access_token. Вопрос в том, как реализовать это через консоль? Т.е. чтобы логин и пароль прописывался непосредственно в консоли.
Ожидаемая работа приложения:
1) Пользователь вводит в консоль логин и пароль,
2) Данные отправляются в вк
3) В ответ отправляется токен для работы с методами vk api

Наброски приложения на nodejs:

```
const https = require('https');    
let url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?client_id=6761494&user_id=210700286&v=5.93';// здесь как-то предать логин, пароль

function doRequest(url) {

    https.get(url, (res) => {

        res.on('data', (d) => {

            //токен приходит здесь

        });

    }).on('error', (e) => {

        console.error(e);

    });

}

doRequest(url);
```

Версия nodejs: 10.11.0

Comment: Не думаю что есть юзеры которые будут вводить в консольное приложение свои данные...

Comment: @SeeSharp, приложение пишется с открытым исходным кодом, как пример работы, без внешнего интерфейса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, прямая авторизация ВКонтакте доступна только доверенным приложениям. (если интересно, подробнее можно почитать [здесь](https://vk.com/dev/auth_direct))
Ниже написал небольшой пример авторизации и последующего вызова метода [users.get](http://htps://vk.com/dev/users.get) с использованием логина и пароля.
*P.S. В примере ниже используется авторизация через оф. приложение для Android, но я всё же настоятельно рекомендую не отходить от правил и договориться с поддержкой о предоставлении доступа к прямой авторизации Вашему приложению.*

```
const request = require('request');    

const USER_CREDENTIALS = {
    login: '',
    password: ''
}


const APP_ID = 2274003;
const APP_SECRET = 'hHbZxrka2uZ6jB1inYsH';
const AUTH_URL = `https://oauth.vk.com/token?grant_type=password&client_id=${APP_ID}&client_secret=${APP_SECRET}&username=${USER_CREDENTIALS.login}&password=` + encodeURIComponent(USER_CREDENTIALS.password);

const TEST_REQUEST = 'https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?v=5.86&access_token=';

doRequest(AUTH_URL, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);

    const response = JSON.parse(res);

    if (response.error) // что-то пошло не так.
        return console.log(response.error);

    // expires - время до истечения жизни токена в секундах.
    const {access_token, expires} = response;
    doRequest(TEST_REQUEST + access_token, (err, response) => {
          if (err) return console.log(err);

          console.log(response);
    });

});

function doRequest(url, callback) {
  request(url, (err, response, body) => {
    if (err) return callback(err);

    callback(null, body);
  });
}
```

Comment: А это ваше приложение или какое-то открытое, которое можно использовать?

Comment: Вы про `2274003`?

Comment: Да, про группу 2274003 и её ключ

Comment: Я ведь уточнил - это [vk.com/app2274003](https://vk.com/app2274003), официальное приложение для Android от ВКонтакте.